# MySQL LIMIT doesn't work / scope

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

I've got that rank query with left join. Trying to limit results to 3 rows, but getting all results instead.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(users.name, users.surname) n,
    total_time v,
    1+(SELECT count(*) from app a WHERE a.total_time > b.total_time) r 
FROM app b
LEFT JOIN users
    ON b.user_id = users.user_id
ORDER by total_time DESC
LIMIT 3
```

I know I could wrap it into another select and then limit it (this is how it was and it used to work) but the change is needed since this is part of more complex query.

Query does react on `DESC` to `ASC` change, but on `LIMIT val` doesn't.
If I change `b.user_id` to `app.user_id` - It throws `#1054 - Unknown column 'app.user_id' in 'on clause'`

How do I limit this to get 3 rows at the most? Where is the scope of the `LIMIT` I used?

Comment: Any chance of a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Try this ORDER by a.total_time DESC

Comment: Error #1054 because app table has already an ALIAS

Answer (score 1):

The query you've shown will return at most three rows. The "scope" of the `LIMIT` clause is with the outermost `SELECT` in the query you've shown.

We could setup a SQL fiddle to demonstrate, but you can just as easily test it. You can't get that query to return more than three rows.